# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress 404 - .NET Microservice

Tags: .net, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to startup a **.NET k8s cluster** running inside the **Docker for Windows** client. I setup an ingress controller like so:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /identity/
            backend:
              serviceName: identity-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 5050
```

With example identity service configured like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: identity-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: identity-service
  ports:
    - port: 5050
      targetPort: 5050
```

The ingress seems to start but when I go to **localhost/identity** I get a **404 Not Found**. The service starts just fine under IIS and docker expose. Other than double checking the ports and the labels, I also made sure that the app returns **200 OK** on default **"/"** route to pass the health check.

Comment: Why are you doing the rewriting target? Also you should access `localhost:5050/identity/`

Comment: First check if the Nginx Ingress Controller pod is running. Then just to validate if the service is reachable, create a `NodePort` service and see if the service is reachable. If so,

Comment: @GauravGahlot Ingress controller is running as mentioned. You cannot expose NodePort on Docker for Windows because the internal IP of the node is inaccessible and the only thing exposed is the external IP as localhost.

Comment: @cookiedough the Ingress should route to the appropriate port and Ingress is exposed on default http port.